# Undetected Id Value Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a matter with my android studio project. In this project, I was using data binding.
it all works fine. But, when I create a new kotlin class the problem occurs. My Activity.kt cannot recognize my id in XML layout.

activity_chapter.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ChapterActivity">

<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:titleTextColor="@color/textColor"
    android:background="@color/columnColor"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:weightSum="4"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_comic"
        android:text="Chapter (10)"
        android:textColor="@color/textColor"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_chapter"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

ChapterActivity.kt

```
package com.tutorial.kotlinfirebasecomicreader

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil
import com.tutorial.kotlinfirebasecomicreader.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class ChapterActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_chapter)

    binding.toolbar
}
}
```

Comment: have you done a clean and rebuild ?

Comment: I have did it a lot of times but I still got the same error
unresolved reference: toolbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is

```
private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
```

Use

```
private lateinit var binding: ActivityChapterBinding
```

Comment: I didn't know there was a change to the binding. I don't think that's the binding was the problem at the first. But since it fixed my error now I get new knowledge. Thanks for your help.